# select an option with partial matching in option value

Tags: jquery, html

my dropdown is like

```
<select id="taskType">
    <option value="xyz:1">Employee Name</option>
    <option value="abc:2">Employee Name</option>
    <option value="123:3">Employee Name</option>
    <option value="efg:4">Employee Name</option>
    <option value="hij:5">Employee Name</option>
   </select>
```

i want to select the option with ":4" in the value.
i tried with string matching

```
$("#taskType option[value^='"+str.match(/(:4)/g)+"']").prop("selected", true);
```

but its not giving the result. I tried with contains function too.

```
$("#taskType option[value:contains(':4')]").prop("selected", true);
```

still didn't got the result.
can anyone help me to find whats the mistake in my code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [attribute ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector

```
$("#taskType option[value$=':4']").prop("selected", true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XB4JV/)

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in this context,

```
$("#taskType option").filter(function(){
   return $(this).val().indexOf(':4') > -1
}).prop("selected", true);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XB4JV/3/)

or use [`attribute contains(*=)`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector

```
$("#taskType option[value*=':4']").prop("selected", true);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XB4JV/2/)

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
$("#taskType option").each(function(){

    if($(this).val().indexOf(":4") != -1)
    {
        $(this).prop("selected", true)
    }

});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4Lva/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$("#taskType option[value~=':4']").prop("selected", true);
```