# jQuery if option text contains string, select it

Tags: jquery, string, text, contains

I want to achieve something similar to this: [select an option with partial matching in option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24052813/select-an-option-with-partial-matching-in-option-value)

But instead of the option being selected based on the value, I want it to be based on the text inside.

For example, I have the following dropdown list. I want that if the option text contains "John", then select it.

```html
<select>
    <option>Jane Doe</option>
    <option>Mary Sue</option>
    <option>John Smith</option>
    <option>Gary Stu</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

   > Description: Select all elements that contain the specified text.

```js
$("select option:contains(John)").prop("selected","selected")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option>Jane Doe</option>
<option>Mary Sue</option>
<option>John Smith</option>
<option>Gary Stu</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Alcove Exactly what was needed but not selected as correct answer? 1up from my side. Been looking for this.